# To understand the description of relative group homology $H_{*}(G,H;\mathbb{Z})$ in terms of free $G$-resolution

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology, tensor-products, short-exact-sequences

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ its subgroup ($H$ need not to be normal). Consider a chain complex $(C_{*}(G), \partial)$ where $C_n(G)$ is the free abelian group generated over the set $G^{n+1}$ and $\partial = \sum_i (-1)^{i} \partial_i$, here $\partial((g_0,g_1, \ldots, g_n))=(g_0,g_1,\ldots, g_{i-1},g_{i+1},\ldots,g_n).$ Now we define relative homology groups $H_{*}(G,H;\mathbb{Z})$ to be the homology groups of the chain complex $(D_{*}, \tilde \partial)$ where

$D_n:= C_{n-1}(H) \oplus C_{n}(G) $
and
$\tilde \partial= \begin{bmatrix} \partial & 0 \\ i_* & -\partial \end{bmatrix}.$

In the paper [The Volume and Chern-Simons Invariant of a Representation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.2049.pdf) it is proved in Theorem$2.1$ that the relative homology can be described in terms of free $G$-resolutions over $K$ which is the kernel of the augmentation map $\epsilon:C_0(G/H) \to \mathbb{Z}.$

To prove this, they first constructed a chain complex $(F_{*}, \delta)$ of free $G$-modules and proved that $H_{*}(F_{*} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} \mathbb{Z})=H_{*+1}(G,H).$

> The construction of $\{F_i\}_{i=0} ^{\infty}$ is as follows:
> Take $F_i= D_{i+1} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}[G]$ for $i \geq 1$ and $F_0=\ker(D_1 \to D_0) \otimes _{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}[G].$

To prove that $(F_{*}, \delta)$ is the free resolution of $K$, it is sufficient to prove that the cokernel of the map $F_1 \to F_0$ is isomorphic to $K$. They write that the image of $F_1 \to F_0$ is the kernel of the map $F_0\cong C_1(G) \xrightarrow{\partial} C_0(G) \xrightarrow{\pi} C_0(G/H)$ and **this is where I am stuck in**.

> Following are the calculations I have done to find the image of $F_1 \to F_0$ (throughout the discusion all $G$-modules are right $G$-modules):

\begin{align}
&\delta\big((n(h,1) \otimes 1, m(g_1,g_2,1) \otimes 1) \otimes g \big)\\
&=\delta\big((n(h,1) \otimes 1,m (g_1,g_2,1) \otimes 1)\big) \otimes g\\
&=\big(n(1-h) \otimes 1, n(h,1) \otimes 1 -m(g_2,1) \otimes 1 + m(g_1,1) \otimes 1 -m(g_1,g_2) \otimes 1)\big) \otimes g\\
&=(0, n(h,1) \otimes 1 -m(g_2,1) \otimes 1 + m(g_1,1) \otimes 1 -m(g_1g_2^{-1},1) \otimes 1) \otimes g.
\end{align}

Under the isomorphism $F_0 \cong C_1(G)$, we have $\delta\big((n(h,1) \otimes 1, m (g_1,g_2,1) \otimes 1) \otimes g \big)=n(hg,g) -m(g_2g,g)+m(g_1g,g) -m(g_1g_2^{-1}g,g).$

> Thus the image of the map $F_1 \to F_0 \to C_1(G)$ is generated by the set
> $S:=\{ n(hg,g) -m(g_2g,g)+m(g_1g,g) -m(g_1g_2^{-1}g,g)~|~h \in H, g_1,g_2,g \in G, n , m \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

Now I see no reason why the set $S$ maps to $0$ under the map $\pi \circ \partial: C_1(G) \to C_0(G/H)$.

To understand it, I have already asked related questions [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536457/to-find-kernel-of-rho-mathbbzg2-to-mathbbzg-h-where-rhog-1-g) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3536583/to-find-image-of-map-c-1h-h-c-2g-g-otimes-mathbbz-mathbbzg) at math StackExchange.

> I am not able to see where I am making mistakes. Please help me to figure it out.
>
> Basically I have to prove that the sequence $F_1 \to F_0 \cong C_1(G) \to K$ is exact at $C_1(G)$

Comment: Am I missing something or does your definition of the chain complexes $C_*$ and $D_*$ not involve the group structure of $G$ and $H$ at all?

Comment: @Christoph: I don't understand your question. Can you please explain? We are not considering $C_n$ as group ring, but $C_n(G)$ has right $G$ action.

Comment: I don't see the group structure of $G$ or this action appear in your definitions of $C_*$ and $D_*$ and hence of $H_*(G;H;\mathbb Z)$. Only the *sets* $G$ and $H$ go into that, which seems very odd to me.

Comment: @Christoph: We don't need the group structure and to think about the action of $G$ on $C_*(G)$. The $G$ action is required just to see that $C_*(G)$ is a projective resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}[G]$. For any given chain complex say $(L_*, \partial)$ we can talk about homologies. Here $H_*(G,H; \mathbb{Z})$ are just homologies of the sequence $D_*$ with suitable boundary maps. Here $D_i$'s are just abelain groups with no $G$ or $H$ action.

Comment: Moreover, $F_i$'s have $G$-action from the right and boundary maps in $F_*$ are $G$-morphisms.